# What's the difference between docker exec and docker exec -it?

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker.  I was trying to implement MySQL using Docker container.

When it comes to executing mysql command in Docker container, the tutorial shows this command `docker exec -it mysql1 mysql -uroot -p`

Docker document mentioned `docker exec` means run a command in container .
The optional `i` tag means  "Keep STDIN open even if not attached" .
The optional `t` tag means  "allocate a pseudo tty" .

What means "Keep STDIN open", what means "attached"?
What means "allocate a pseudo tty"?

I'm not familiar with shell commands. I don't know why '-it' should be added here.
Will it be different if I just type `docker exec mysql1 mysql -uroot -p`?

So confused, looking forward to any help... thanks...

Comment: (If you just need to run MySQL commands, run the `mysql -h 127.0.0.1` client tool on your host.  You don’t need `docker exec` and its attendant root-level privilege to do it.)

Comment: In that case, I have to have mysql client pre-installed in host environment, right?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`-i` -- Don't just run the program in the background with no way to send it data; keep it open to accepting input of some form.

`-t` -- Specifically, give me a place to type commands to send to the program, as if I had an ssh or telnet session open to a remote machine I could feed commands to.

Together they essentially make it so that you can run e.g. your `mysql1` program as if you were just running it normally locally, outside a Docker container.

Comment: So, `-t` gives me an interface to write commands, and `-i` provide a tunnel for program inside container to receive the written commands. Am I getting it right?

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation makes everything clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

[Will Cain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9778169/will-cain)'s answer is more complete, but in short, giving `-it` lets you get inside the container in **interactive** mode i.e -
`-t` : Allocate a pseudo-tty
`-i` : Keep STDIN open even if not attached

[Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#general-form) for docker run that explains those arguements.

**NOTE**: `docer exec` is for running a command inside an already running container. Hence it is extremely useful for debugging conatiners.